# Frontend v/s backend problem isolation

Tags: frontend, backend

This is very generic question, still I hope someone will provide pointers.

In a web application, say Facebook or Amazon or any web site, how do I isolate if a problem is on frontend (client side) or backend (server side)? I feel there has to be very basic troubleshooting steps available to find out this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to debug and make sure everything is working properly on the client side. If all the values are right, then it must be the server-side.

Though, nowadays code can get pretty complex so it really depends on your skill-level and experience/knowledge. If you are a beginner then I would recommend learning more and more client-side and server-side in order to know what to debug.

The majority of the time as you are learning you'll probably have to resort to asking other people if you aren't at an advanced level, which is perfectly fine. Just ask away on sites like SO and the more problems you run into, the more tips you'll acquire which will make you a better debugger and developer.

Answer (score 0):

Since server side part is under your control, you can easily enable logging so you'll see where a problem lies.

Client side is a bit more tricky since it's executed on user's browser, so it's not under your direct control.

But, if an exception occurs on client side, you can always catch it and send that information to your server using AJAX with some info like "clientError", where you can log it as that, so with basic usage of grep, you'll know where the actual problem lies.

If there's a client side problem and an AJAX call fails (for example, client has network problems), you can put error info in a cookie and collect it afterwards.